# getElementByID with dynamic ID

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

Hi I have a problem with my javascript within an ASP SharePoint web part page. The page is built the same as any other ASP page so the fact that its hosted within SharePoint shouldn't make any difference.

The problem is with my javascript within the page. I have Html Table made up of 8 cells. For each of these cells I am displaying a different div with different data within it onmouseover.

The problem comes with the ID for the Divs that I am trying to display. The Divs ID is changed at runtime but also changes daily so cant be inputted manually.

HTML:

```
<div id="Main" style="display: none;
    <div id="hover1" runat="server" style="display: none">
        Test
    </div>
</div>

<table id="Table3" runat="server" >
    <tr id="Tr8" runat="server" >
        <td id="status1" runat="server" onmouseover="getDataXML('hover1')" onmouseout="hideDiv('hover1')">
            Received
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The id 'hover1' at runtime is replaced with something like 'ctl00_m_g_6ddac285_ceb9_4b5a_9095_c4b216cf7dfd_ctl00_hover1'

Javascript:

```
function getDataXML(getID) {
        document.getElementById('Main').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById(getID).style.display = "block";
    };
```

The javascript works if I take the ID which is generated and hard code it but the ID changes daily meaning it becomes a problem. Any help I would greatly appreciate

Regards,

Comment: Forgot to say the error I get is 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object required'

Comment: Can't you keep a same class or something in the *daily generated* div..? anyway you'll need some sort of relationship between the two...

Comment: If there is numeric correspondence between `status` and `hover` elements without interference from other IDs, then just grab the trailing number with a regex and use `querySelector` with the *attribute-ends-with* selector to select it. `document.querySelector("div[id$=hover]" + n)`

Comment: Could you maybe select the Main div element first and than select n-th child of this element? So you can send n-th child as a parameter to the getDataXml function and select the right div later. Parent-child relations.

Comment: Is the div generated via sharepoint, or is it an asp:div? It looks like asp is doing it, given the ID that you indicated. If that's the case, you can look into using a staticID for your divs. This is possible with asp.net controls.

Comment: Can I get some clarification, please? So you have 8 divs within your #main div, and 8 table cells that correspond to each #main div? You want it so that when you hover on the table cell, it displays the content from the corresponding div?

Answer (score 2):

Set clientIdMode = static to the element

```
 <div id="hover1" clientIdMode="static" runat="server" style="display: none">
```

Comment: This is interesting. I didn't know this existed. I can use this at work! lol. Thanks. -- Not OP.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass clientId like this:

```
onmouseover="getDataXML('<%=hover1.ClientID %>')"
```

or alternatively set **ClientIDMode** to  **Static**, but in that case if you change div id in aspx, you have to explicitly change where you have used Id and it will be difficult to catch becuse there will be no compile time error.

Comment: tried both of these and it doesn't solve the issue get exactly the same error